# Integrating customised APIs in Spartacus Storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

our Hybris instance has some custom REST APIs, for example the *addEntry*. This version of the API requires an extra boolean parameter in the payload, let's call it *fooBar*.
Here’s an example of payload:

`{"quantity": 1, "product": {"code": "1234567"}, "fooBar": false}`

Here’s the list of what we’ve done in order to have this extra parameter in the service that actually made the http call:

- Overridden the **AddToCartComponent**

  - Modified the **addToCart** method passing the *fooBar* parameter to the **addEntry** method of the **E2ActiveCartService**
- Extended ActiveCartService in E2ActiveCartService

  - Modified the **addEntry** method passing the *fooBar* parameter to the **addEntry** method of the **E2MultiCartService**
- Extended **MultiCartService** in **E2MultiCartService**

  - Modified the **addEntry** method passing the *fooBar* parameter to the payload of the **E2CartAddEntry** action
- Implemented a copy of the **CartAddEntry** action (called **E2CartAddEntry**) with its own type (i.e. *'[E2-Cart-entry] Add Entry'*)
- Implemented a new **CartEntryEffects** (called **E2CartEntryEffects**) that listens to the **E2CartAddEntry** action

  - Created a second effect called **processesIncrement$** that dispatches the **CartActions.CartProcessesIncrement** action (we did this because the **E2CartAddEntry** cannot extends the **EntityProcessesIncrementAction** class)
  - Copied the **addEntry$** effect from the original **CartEntryEffects** adding the *fooBar* parameter to the **add** method of the **E2CartEntryConnector**
- Extended **CartEntryConnector** in **E2CartEntryConnector**

  - Modified the **add** method passing the *fooBar* parameter to the **add** method of the **E2CartEntryAdapter**
- Extended **CartEntryAdapter** in **E2CartEntryAdapter**

  - Modified the abstract **add** method adding the *fooBar* parameter
- Created **E2OccCartEntryAdapter** that extends **OccCartEntryAdapter** and implements **E2CartEntryAdapter**

  - Modified the **add** method adding *fooBar* to the payload of the POST call made from **HttpClient**
- Finally, in our main module we changed the providers:

```
[
    { provide: ActiveCartService, useClass: E2ActiveCartService },
    { provide: MultiCartService, useClass: E2MultiCartService },
    E2CartEntryEffects,
    { provide: CartEntryConnector, useClass: E2CartEntryConnector },
    { provide: E2CartEntryAdapter, useClass: E2OccCartEntryAdapter },
]
```

This solution seems to work but we think that's pretty complex for a relatively simple change and we would like to know if our approach is correct or if there is a better, cleaner way.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems like the correct way for this specific use case.

You did not exactly specify what `fooBar` is used for, but I assume, it's used and can be toggled inside the top-level layer (in UI component) and has to be passed by all other layers down to the adapter.

On the other hand, if for example, `fooBar` would just be a property of the `Product` model, then it would be a matter of extending only the 'Product' model + the changes where it's important (component, adapter), and all other places could be left intact (would just pass extended model).

Can you please give some more context of the required change, so we can better understand it, and make it easier in the future?

In near future, we are considering unifying the payload of our facade services through all the layers in Spartacus, so adding more context to any core logic will be much simplified (basically will come down to the second example, regarding extending the `Product` model).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We simply want to use this additional parameter in the payload of the add Entry API.
The parameter value (a boolean) depends on a checkbox present in the PDP page.